# What ida:AadInstance should i set to make my Azure AD B2C work?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am following this [code sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi) in which they suggest me to use `ida:AadInstance` with value `<your-tenant-name>.b2clogin.com`. But when I am running this code I am getting the following error:

> IDX20108: The address specified 'System.String' is not valid as per HTTPS scheme. Please specify an https address for security reasons. If you want to test with http address, set the RequireHttps property  on IDocumentRetriever to false.
> Parameter name: address

The place where i am getting this error is when i am trying to get result for `config`. This is my code:

```
private void RetrieveMetadata()
        {
            _synclock.EnterWriteLock();
            try
            {
                OpenIdConnectConfiguration config = Task.Run(_configManager.GetConfigurationAsync).Result;
                _issuer = config.Issuer;
                _keys = config.SigningKeys;
            }
            finally
            {
                _synclock.ExitWriteLock();
            }
        }
```

This block of code is present in the [code sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi/blob/master/TaskService/App_Start/OpenIdConnectCachingSecurityTokenProvider.cs) inside the directory `TaskService\App_Start\OpenIdConnectCachingSecurityTokenProvider.cs`

My current configuration in web.config:
`<add key="ida:AadInstance" value="UPES.b2clogin.com" />`.Can anyone suggest me the correct value for ida:AadInstance to prevent the mentioned error?

Web.config file keys:

```
 <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="ida:AadInstance" value="https://UPES.b2clogin.com/{0}/{1}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration" />
    <add key="ida:Tenant" value="https://UPES2020.onmicrosoft.com" />
    <add key="ida:ClientId" value="fgd-b420-dfg-991d-2bgfd955fc" />
    <add key="ida:SignUpSignInPolicyId" value="b2c_1_SiUpIn" />
    <!-- The following settings is used for requesting access tokens -->
    <add key="api:ReadScope" value="read" />
    <add key="api:WriteScope" value="write" />
  </appSettings>
```

error screenshot:
[image]

web.config of TaskService:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301879
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="ida:AadInstance" value="https://UPES.b2clogin.com" />
    <add key="ida:Tenant" value="https://UPES2020.onmicrosoft.com" />
    <add key="ida:ClientId" value="ID correctly added" />
    <add key="ida:SignUpSignInPolicyId" value="b2c_1_SiUpIn" />
    <!-- The following settings is used for requesting access tokens -->
    <add key="api:ReadScope" value="read" />
    <add key="api:WriteScope" value="write" />
  </appSettings>
  <!--
    For a description of web.config changes see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235367.

    The following attributes can be set on the <httpRuntime> tag.
      <system.Web>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
      </system.Web>
  -->
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.8" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-13.0.0.0" newVersion="13.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.14.0.0" newVersion="6.14.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.14.0.0" newVersion="6.14.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.7.0" newVersion="5.2.7.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.4.0.0" newVersion="5.4.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.4.0.0" newVersion="5.4.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WsFederation" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.14.0.0" newVersion="6.14.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Even after trying ```https://UPES.b2clogin.com/{0}/{1}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration``` as suggested by https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/42162 still i am getting this error. What else i should check?

Comment: The [linked documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-authentication-sample-web-app-with-api?tabs=visual-studio#step-4-configure-the-sample-web-api) doesn't mention the path part of the above URL at all - which has C# format specifiers in it, presumably being intended to be replaced by other values. Supplying these in a config file would be strange, and probably not what the GitHub poster meant. By this guidance, the correct value would be `https://UPES.b2clogin.com`

Comment: Hello thank you for reply. I made the change but still the error showed up. I have attached the screenshot of the error.

Comment: Oh. I see the version with the format specifiers is as the [code sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi/blob/master/TaskService/Web.config) actually has. I wish they'd be consistent.

Comment: I think its correctly added. I downloaded the whole template form git and made changes in values of web.config only. FYR, I have attached the web.config of TaskService as well.

Comment: Yes they are consistent.

Comment: I mean, I wish Azure code samples were consistent in how they structure settings and use the same format with the same name everywhere. Most other examples of Azure AD integration don't use this format for AadInstance. I further noticed that the issues page for that sample has a lot of remarks about this sample being out of date and one of them mentions an [up to date sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/4-WebApp-your-API/4-2-B2C). Is there any particular reason you need to use an old sample?

Comment: Actually I am looking for sample compatible with ASP.NET not core. I got this link from Microsoft documents

Comment: I guess the exception is because of Azure setting and not the code issue. Because the exceptions says unable to retrieve document.

Comment: Take a look at the arguments passed to `OpenIdConnectCachingSecurityTokenProvider` [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi/blob/master/TaskService/App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs). This is using the format expression to construct a complete metadata URL, and with your value of `ida:Tenant` will copy a complete URL into a string that is already a URL. So I think the fix is to change your `Tenant` value to UPES.b2clogin.com, matching the convention that the code sample uses in their config: `<add key="ida:Tenant" value="fabrikamb2c.onmicrosoft.com" />`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245366/discussion-between-psychonaut007-and-tom-w).